# Stats on website

Tags: civimember

Is it possible to get stats on the number of members and push them to a webpage so that they are always updated? Is there some extension that might do it?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Drupal, you can use Views with its aggregation to handle this. I helped someone do pretty much exactly this.  I also used the "Views Field Views" module to show a bunch of aggregated stats all in one view.

Comment: So using views_aggregator module and/or instead of views_calc module? Or using the built-in views one?

Comment: @KarinG I'm agnostic!  I used built-in Views aggregation to get numbers.  As for Views Field Views - my client had a need to get multiple unrelated numbers on one View (e.g. number of current members, number of activities of type "Distributed Flyer" in the last month).  So we created multiple views, then used Views Field Views to put them all together.

Comment: Very cool! I'm going to add that to my list of things to try

Comment: Yep Views Field View is great. We use it a lot eg to pull together details about a range of Activities in to a single display using the contact ID as the contextual filter. It has killed a few sites when we have used this for a large number of rows however! I agree also re Aggregation. I would use that just publish eg 'number of members', or, 'number of petition signers' etc

Comment: I would like to show total number of current civi members, new, current and grace on my site but on a Wordpress platform, perhaps in a widget or on specific pages.  Is there a plugin or an extension that will do this for me please?  I've searched civi extensions but can't seem to find anything to fit.

Comment: @peterb This will receive much more attention as its own question.  However, in short, I don't believe there is.  However, it would be a very easy plugin to write.

Answer (score 3):

That's CMS specific -> For Drupal you could write a small module that has a query that pulls the count from the CiviCRM database using mysql -> creates a block for it -> which you can then place anywhere on a Drupal site on the blocks configuration page.