# Number of people signed up

Tags: wordpress, summaryfields, civipetiton

When using CiviCampaign's CiviPetition it would be nice to be able to place a field of the number of people that have signed up facing the public (same goes for e.g. number of members, etc.). I know this is CMS dependent, having read it may be possible using Drupal. Any ideas for e.g. Wordpress (probable needs PHP somewhere!?).
Cheers

Comment: Been asked in the Drupal world, but no Wordpress: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12848/stats-on-website